# Select distinct vertex in OrientDb

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I have a database with the following data:

```
Vertex

Country              City                 Hotel
--------------       --------------       ---------------------------
ID      Name         ID      Name         ID      Name
--------------       --------------       ---------------------------
#16:0   Italia       #17:0   Roma         #18:0   Residence Barberini
                                          #18:1   Santa Prisca

Edges

In                           PartOf
---------------              -------------
From     To                  From     To
---------------              -------------
#18:0    #16:0               #17:0    #16:0
#18:0    #17:0
#18:1    #17:0
```

I would like to extract all the hotels in Italy where they can be extracted directly following the edge **In** or indirectly following the edge **PartOf** and for each element **PartOf** another following the edge **In**.

Basically the result expected is

```
#18:0   Residence Barberini   (direct from Italia)
#18:1   Santa Prisca          (traversing Roma)
```

I used the following query

```
select distinct(h) from 
(select in('in') as h from (traverse in('partOf') from #16:0))
```

and I get the following results:

```
#18:0
#18:0, #18:1
```

How it is possible to retrieve only the distinct Hotels efficiently?
The expected result should be

```
#18:0
#18:1   (instead of #18:0, #18:1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
select distinct(h) from 
(select in('in') as h from (traverse in('partOf') from #16:0) unwind h)
```